# Is it possible to use a regular Windows VPN connection to connect with an openvpn server?

Tags: openvpn

Just that.

Is it possible, or you need necessarily an openvpn client? Clients need to be identified by private keys (certs).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the OpenVPN client. It's not compatible with  OpenVPN as it uses a custom security protocol.

Comment: thanks a lot Lucas. Is there any other vpn linux server software compatible with the Windows VPN?

Comment: well, there is PPTP server for Linux, but I from a security stand point it's a bit cheezy.

Comment: Openswan running L2TP?

Comment: That might be a better option :p